# deprecated functions, is it breaking my site?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Error logs are showing several deprecated errors these are:

```
[19-Jan-2022 22:55:27 UTC] The is_ajax function is deprecated since version 6.1.0. Replace with wp_doing_ajax.

[19-Jan-2022 22:39:06 UTC] woocommerce_add_order_item_meta is deprecated since version 3.0.0! Use woocommerce_new_order_item instead.
```

We then installed Deprecated Calls plugin which displays is_ajax() used in **wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/wc-deprecated-functions.php on line 54.**

We then checked such file which only gives us this on line 1136

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'is_ajax' ) ) {

    /**
     * Is_ajax - Returns true when the page is loaded via ajax.
     *
     * @deprecated 6.1.0
     * @return bool
     */
    function is_ajax() {
        wc_deprecated_function( 'is_ajax', '6.1.0', 'wp_doing_ajax' );
        return function_exists( 'wp_doing_ajax' ) ? wp_doing_ajax() : Constants::is_defined( 'DOING_AJAX' );
    }
}
```

Could deprecated functions break a WordPress site? Yesterday we had between 160,000 - 220,000 requests made to the site which crippled the server ultimately causing the site to go offline and display "Error establishing connetion to database". When enabling attack mode on cloudflare the site was back online however some plugins and features were not working from this point onwards.

However when checking cloudflare their only appears to be traffic coming from the site itself and all of the thousands and thousands of requests are the same (see picture below):

[image]

Today we see requests from our site itself which are being challenged by cloudflare

[image]

I understand this is a very broad question but we remain quite anxious after yesterday , can conflicting plugins cause a self inflicted DDoS? is deprecated functions possibly causing issues?

Comment: "Deprecated" in software development means, a function/feature will currently still work - but will eventually be removed in a future version. The WooCommerce developers apparently are already aware of this specific issue - the file you found the function in, is named `wc-deprecated-functions.php` after all.

Comment: That this has something to do with your current performance problems, is however rather unlikely. Your first screenshot for example is about `/sitemap.xml`, and AJAX should not have anything to do with that at all.

Comment: De-activate the plugins that are not compatible with WooCommerce 6.1.0

Comment: Thank you for your responses @CBroe - cloudflare is showing 150-220k requests from the IP in the first screenshot , some other query strings and paths include ?-1%20OR%202%2B127-127-1=0%2B0%2B0%2B1%20--%20 and /(12).(d+).*(( , I suspect a ddos attack, I did initally think have I or some conflicted plugins caused a self inflicted ddos attack but I now doubt it after some research